# Compare multidimensional array values by key in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array of the products as in the sample below. Products can be **two**, or **three** and **more**. In this example, three.

```php
$all_products = array(
    'product_1'       =>array(
        'price'       =>'$100',
        'quantity'    =>'2pcs.',
        'availability'=>'In Stock',
        'manufacturer'=>'Apple'),
    'product_2'       =>array(
        'price'       =>'$200',
        'quantity'    =>'2pcs.',
        'availability'=>'In Stock',
        'manufacturer'=>''),
    'product_3'       =>array(
        'price'       =>'$300',
        'quantity'    =>'2pcs.',
        'availability'=>'In Stock',
        'manufacturer'=>'')
);
```

I need to compare values of the products by each key. To highlight rows in the compare table where price, quantity, availability, or manufacturer is different.

I have tried this function to check which values are different and return one temp array:

```php
function compare_array($array, $key) {
    $temp_array = array();
    $i = 0;
    $key_array = array();

    foreach($array as $val) {
        if (isset($val[$key])) {
            if (!in_array($val[$key], $key_array)) {
                $key_array[$i] = $val[$key];
                $temp_array[$i] = $val;
            } 
        }
        $i++;
    }

    return $temp_array;
}
```

and then:

```php
foreach ($all_products as $products) {
    foreach ($products as $product_key => $val) {
        foreach ($this->compare_array($all_products, $product_key) as $temp_value) { 
            if ($val != $temp_value) {
                $style[$product_key] = 'style="background-color: lightblue;"';//style for highlight    
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Problem is when some value in array is empty. Like in this example, `manufacturer`.

Maybe someone has more light solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need compare values of the products by each key. To highlight rows
>   in the compare table where price, quantity, availability, or
>   manufacturer is different.

If you want to highlight all products unless all of them have exactly the same price, quantity, availability, or manufacturer.

function:

```
function productsIdentical(array &$products) : bool
{
    if (count($products) < 2) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException("You should pass at least 2 products to compare");
    }

    $compare = '';
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        ksort($product); //to make comparison of key order insensitive
        $sha = sha1(json_encode($product));
        if (empty($compare)) {
            $compare = $sha;
        } elseif ($sha !== $compare) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

returns `true` only if all products' fields have exactly the same keys and value, otherwise it returns `false`

so you use it this way:

```
$identicalFlag = productsIdentical($all_products);
if ($identicalFlag === false) {
    echo "Products are not identical:" . PHP_EOL;

    $nonIdenticalProductsArr = array_keys($all_products);
    echo "Non identical products are:" . PHP_EOL;
    print_r($nonIdenticalProductsArr);

    //do your styling  on $nonIdenticalProducts

} else {
    echo "Products are identical" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

> Output:

for identical products:

```
Products are identical
```

for non identical:

```
Products are not identical:
Non identical products are:
Array
(
    [0] => product_1
    [1] => product_2
    [2] => product_3
)
```

Or if you want to detect every product field that is not the same across all products in the array use this function:

```
function getFieldsNonIdentical(array &$products) : array
{
    if (count($products) < 2) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException("You should pass at least 2 products to compare");
    }

    $compareArr = [];
    $keyDifferentArr = [];
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        foreach($product as $key => $val) {
            if (!key_exists($key, $compareArr)) {
                $compareArr[$key] = $val;
            } elseif ($compareArr[$key] !== $val) {
                $keyDifferentArr[$key] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return array_keys($keyDifferentArr);
}
```

this way:

```
$fieldsNonIdentical = getFieldsNonIdentical($all_products);

if (!empty($fieldsNonIdentical)) {
    echo "Fields that are non identical:" . PHP_EOL;

    print_r($fieldsNonIdentical);

    //do your styling

    $nonIdenticalStyle = 'style="background-color: lightblue;"';
    $styleArr = [];
    foreach ($fieldsNonIdentical as $key => $value) {
        $styleArr[$value] = $nonIdenticalStyle;
    }

    echo "Non Identical fields styling is:" . PHP_EOL;
    print_r($styleArr);
} else {
    echo "All fields in all products are the same." . PHP_EOL;
}
```

> Output

for identical:

```
All fields in all products are the same.
```

for non identical:

```
Fields that are non identical:
Array
(
    [0] => price
    [1] => manufacturer
)
Non Identical fields styling is:
Array
(
    [price] => style="background-color: lightblue;"
    [manufacturer] => style="background-color: lightblue;"
)
```

Comment: Working. Thank you.