# Compare multidimensional array values by key where child arrays can be empty or different in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Very similar situation in this answer: [Compare multidimensional array values by key in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58809613/compare-multidimensional-array-values-by-key-in-php/58811601#58811601)
Working when all child keys are identical, but problem when some child arrays are not identical or empty. So I decide to ask another question.
Sample of the possible array:

```
$all_products = array(
    'product_1'       =>array(
        'price'       =>'$100',
        'brand'       =>'Apple'
    ),
    'product_2'       =>array(
        'price'       =>'$200',
        'quantity'    =>'2pcs.',
        'available'   =>'In Stock'
    ),
    'product_3'       =>array(
    )
);
```

In this sample all child arrays are different.

---

```
|key name | product_1 | product_2 | product_3 |
-----------------------------------------------
| price   | $100      | $200      |           | row should be highlighted
----------------------------------------------- 
| quantity|           | 2pcs.     |           | row should be highlighted
----------------------------------------------- 
|available|           | In Stock  |           | row should be highlighted
----------------------------------------------- 
| brand   |   Apple   |           |           | row should be highlighted
-----------------------------------------------
```

I need compare this products and highlight rows where data in row is different. If all data in row are the same no highlighting.
I have tried  to use the way in mentioned answer [Compare multidimensional array values by key in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58809613/compare-multidimensional-array-values-by-key-in-php/58811601#58811601)
Is working fine when all keys in a child rows are identical, but in this situation does not work...
So no success. I got stuck at all...
If anybody can help I'll be very thankful.

Comment: Do you have "finish" param or you can have more that those 4 (price, quantity, available, brand) ? And you want to `highlight rows where data in row is different` => different when you compare with what ? If you have row1 = row2 and row 3 = row 4, but row1 != row3, what will you highlight ?

Comment: @MickaëlLeger this is definitely page like compare products and they can have infinite properties.

Comment: Can be more ( 5, or 10, or more) parameters like those 4 (price, quantity, available, brand)

Comment: I don’t get what you want here. Please give an example of when you would _not_ want to highlight a row then - like when the price was $100 for all three products, or what? _“but in this situation does not work...”_ - give us a proper problem description - “does not work” is not one.

Comment: in  case when, for example, "available"  will be "In Stock" for all products, this row not highlighted. The same with another rows. In child array rows ( values by key name) can be more, or less. Products also can be more, or just only two.

Comment: @04FS  “but in this situation does not work...”  I mean with the function provided in the attached link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58809613/compare-multidimensional-array-values-by-key-in-php/58811601#58811601

Comment: If you have a problem with what was suggested as solution over there - then you should probably rather have handled that over there as well, instead of creating a new question. Plus, I still don’t see how this “situation” here is supposed to be fundamentally different from what you had in the other question to begin with …?

Comment: @ 04FS Is different because child arrays are not identical. So if you do not understand my question it is not necessary vote down my question. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I clearly understood you then this is your solution:

```
$ar_keys = [];
$keys_highl = [];
$keys_values = [];
foreach($all_products as $prod_name => $data){
    foreach($data as $key => $val){
        if (!in_array($key, $ar_keys) && !empty($val)) {
            array_push($ar_keys, $key); 
            $keys_highl[$key] = 0;
            $keys_values[$key] = [];
        } 
        $keys_values[$key][] = $val;
    }
} 

$max_length = count($all_products); 

foreach($keys_highl as $k => $high){
    $keys_highl[$k] = 
          count(array_unique($keys_values[$k])) == 1 
          && count($keys_values[$k]) == $max_length 
          ?  0 : 1;
}

 print_r($keys_highl); 
 return;
```

Working [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/267314734c79741bd732c9ee7beb8d5d29292fff)

EDITED:
I have edited little bit your code. I add additional condition in case if the child  array some keys are empty at all. Was:

```
if (!in_array($key, $ar_keys)) {
```

Changed to this:

```
if (!in_array($key, $ar_keys) && !empty($val)) {
```

Comment: @ Aksen P I have tried your code but seems does not work in all combination. Please check this DEMO Link: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cfe79ee46d708575df5d9512e259be12fd9959d9

Comment: @K.B., sorry, `$max_length = count($all_products); ` should be instead of `$max_length = count($keys_values); `

Comment: Nice Thank's a lot, working fine. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/697aff6d22b5f529931e986bd99683b1446ac241

Comment: @K.B., as you wish, this edition prevents of being all cells empty which means `ok`, cause it's the same value in each one. `null` is a `value` also. Nevermind, as you wish

Comment: @  Aksen P Yes, because if in some key (which values we need to compare) all values empty, it's mean that all values equal, but with previous code I got that they are not equal and I edited your code little bit.  Anyway it is very helpful and I'm thankful for your time.